# Age calculator using loop,switch and if statements and arrays

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm new to programming and was programming an age calculator as an exercise for myself using switch and if statements, arrays, loops. My programs first asks the user to enter their age and based on that input it checks the array ageCriteria ranges using the loop, then inside that loop there is an if statements that checks if the age matches with ageCriteria array. If it matches then it will proceed to the switch statements that have different outputs on what age range do you fall. My code is not working when I'm trying to execute it. If anyone knows please help.

```js
var age = prompt("Please enter your age");
age = parseInt(age);
var ageCriteria = [age > 0 && age < 10, age > 10 && age < 18, age > 18 && age < 30, age > 30 && age < 40, age > 40 && age < 60];

//FOR LOOPS
for (var i = 0; i < age; i++) {
  if (age == ageCriteria[i]) {
    switch (ageCriteria[i]) {
      case 1:
        console.log("You're a baby");
        break;

      case 2:
        console.log("You're a teenager");
        break;

      case 3:
        console.log("You're an adult");
        break;

      case 4:
        console.log("You're middle aged");
        break;

      default:
        console.log("You're old");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"...is not working"_ is a meaningless "error description". Please describe what you expect the code to do, what it does instead, if there are any errors (which should be then part of the question) and if possible what you've already tried to fix this on your own.

Comment: If you `console.log(ageCriteria)` you will see that it only has `false` and maybe `true`.

Comment: You should also have another look on how the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement works.

Comment: Just so you are aware if someone is 10, 18, 30, 40 or 60 this will never return a value (even when you fix your switch statement) as you have done less than and greater than, you need to include a `<=` or `>=` (less than or equal to, greater than or equal to) for one criteria that matches that age (i.e. `>= 13` and `<18` would be a teenager and would include 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 but not 18)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ageCriteria` is an array of boolean values. If you enter, for example, a value of 9, then ageCriteria is `[true, false, false, false, false]`.

Later, you have an `if` statement where you compare the actual age (value 9) with the array values (booleans) and use the age as the index.

You should see the following:

- it prints 'Your're old' once (because the array values are booleans, not integers, none of the cases matches so we see the default case)
- it crashes, because the array has only 5 items but you try to access `a[0]..a[9]` (`a[4]` is the allowed maximum)

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone explained to you why your solution does not work, here is a working one in case you want an example.

```
var age = prompt("Please enter your age");
age = parseInt(age);
var ageCriteria = [age > 0 && age < 10, age > 10 && age < 18, age > 18 && age < 30, age > 30 && age < 40, age > 40 && age < 60];

function getResult(index){
  switch(index){
      case 0:
        console.log("You're a baby");
        break;

      case 1:
        console.log("You're a teenager");
        break;

      case 2:
        console.log("You're an adult");
        break;

      case 3:
        console.log("You're middle aged");
        break;

      default:
        console.log("You're old");
    }
  }

for(let x=0; x<ageCriteria.length; x++){
  if(ageCriteria[x] == true){
    getResult(x);
  }
}
```

This is a working solution, by the way in the `ageCriteria` array there are some edge cases where it does not work because you are using `<` or `>` instead of `<=` or `>=` so have a look at that issue. For example the application does nothing if you enter 10 (because you are not checking for that case).

Comment: I understand now why my code was not working. I looked at your code then I understood. Thanks @AliBeyit

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, your "ageCriteria" will contain boolean values not integers (you should see what you're comparing it with)
Secondly, the loop needs to be iterated over the criteria array.
Hopefully these two hints will help you figure out.